# How to monitor pod preemption event

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, metrics, preemption, pod-priority

I have a bunch of Rancher clusters I take care of and on some of them developers use `PriorityClasses` to ensure that some of the more important workloads get scheduled. The 3 `PriorityClasses` are in 3 digits range so they will not interfere with the default ones. However, at present none of the `PriorityClasses` is set as default and neither is the `preemptionPolicy` set so it defaults to `PreemptLowerPriority`.

None of the rancher, longhorn, prometheus, grafana, etc., workloads have `priorityClassName` set.

Long story short, I believe this causes havoc on the cluster when resources are in short supply.

Before I take my opinion to the developers I would like to collect some data to back up my story.

The question: How do I detect if the pod was Terminated due to Preemption?

I tried to google the subject but couldn't find anything. I was hoping `kube state metrics` would have something but I didn't find anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to look for convincing data like the pod termination reason with help of kubectl.

You can see the last restart logs of a container using the following command:

> kubectl logs podname -c containername --previous

You can also use the following command to check the lifecycle events sent by the kubelet to the apiserver about the pod.

> kubectl describe pod podname

Finally, You can also write a final message to /dev/termination-log, and this will show up as described in [the docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/determine-reason-pod-failure/#writing-and-reading-a-termination-message).

To use kubectl commands with rancher kindly refer to [this](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.5/en/cluster-admin/cluster-access/kubectl/) documentation page.

Comment: Hello @WytrzymałyWiktor, I'm working on this.

Comment: Hi @piotr-malec. Thanks for the suggestions but this didn't get me what I need. When preemption happens for pods created by a deployment or sts the pod with lover priority is terminated and another one with a different name scheduled and I don't know the name of the pod which was terminated. --previous won't work here as this is not a restart and writing to termination-log gives me a way to influence termination-log content based on app's internal logic which in my case has nothing to do with. The pod is simply ejected by another one with higher priority so the app has no clue why is died.

Comment: I think I will try to solve this with prometheus metric by gathering info from kube state metrics on all pod creation and termination by node. I will also expose metrics which tell me which pods have assigned priority classes. This way I should see when pod with priority assigned initiates terminations on the same node. I can also confirm if allocatable resources were low on that node.